# Go: builtin make - does the capacity make a difference

Tags: go, slice

Consider wanting to dynamically fill an array/slice with exactly `5` elements. No more, and no less.

## (1) Slice with initial length 0

```
sl := []string{}
for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
    sl = append(sl, "abc")
}
```

## (2) Slice with initial length set, no capacity

```
sl := make([]string, 5)
for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
    s1[i] = "abc"
}
```

## (3) Slice with initial length set, capacity given

```
sl := make([]string, 5, 5)
for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
    sl[i] = "abc"
}
```

---

My feeling tells me that #1 is not the *best* solution, but I am wondering why I would choose #2 over #3 or vice versa? (performance-wise)

Comment: 2) and 3) are absolutely identical. Form 3) is useful if you want a slice of len 20 but a cap 200 (to allow allocation free appending of 180 elements). Version 1) is perfectly okay unless you know your slice will grow to some assessable large extent.

Comment: You left out (4) where you do `make([]string, 0, 5)` and then use `append` as in (1). That's typically done in cases where the capacity setting is more of a guess/estimate/upper-bound or where for other reasons it's more convenient to use something like `append` or have the slice length grow during the loop rather than use explicit indexing.

Comment: Another side note, (2) and (3) could use `for i := range sl`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, whenever you have a question about performance, [benchmark](http://golang.org/pkg/testing/#hdr-Benchmarks) and [profile](http://blog.golang.org/profiling-go-programs).

Secondly, I don't see any difference here. Considering that this code

```
s := make([]int, 5)
fmt.Println(cap(s))
```

[prints 5](http://play.golang.org/p/pXHllXnult), your #2 and #3 are basically the same.

Comment: Did not know about `cap` - this surely helps a lot. Thank you :-)